# Function only executing once

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a list set up called `lines` which has every line set up separated. Then those get sent to another function called `rdline()` that reads it. I have set up an alert to see what goes through it and it only alerts once when there are multiple entries in the array.

```js
var ms = false;
var ss;
var c;
var lc;
var lines = [];
var currset;
var win;
var sendline = 0;
var op = function() {
  document.getElementById('rd').innerHTML = "Reading...";
  ss = document.getElementById('t').innerHTML;
  c = document.getElementById('t').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = "";
  lc = 0;
  lines = [];
  currset = [];
  setLines(c);
}
var setLines = function(cont) {
  for (i = 0; i < cont.length; i++) {
    if (cont[i] == ";") {
      lines[lc] = currset.join("").replace("<br>", "") + " ";
      lc++;
      currset = [];

    } else {
      currset[i] = cont[i];
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    rdline(lines[i])
  }
  
}
var rdline = function(parg) {
  //EXECUTING ONCE!
  alert(parg)
  //the rest should be fine
  var pl = [];
  var toplace = [];
  var pcount = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < parg.length; i++) {
    if (parg[i] == " ") {
      pl[pcount] = toplace.join("");
      pcount++;
      toplace = [];
    } else {
      toplace[i] = parg[i];
    }
  }
  //functions
  if (pl[0] == "$setupmemes") {
    ms = true;
    win = window.open("", "", "height=800", "width=800")
  }
  if (ms == true) {
    if (pl[0] == "expand") {
      win.document.write('dongs')
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = ss;
}
```

```css
code {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button onClick='op()'>Run</button>
<span id='rd'></span>
<br />
<br />
<code contenteditable="true" id='t'></code>
```

Run the snippet and type:

$setupmemes;
expand;

Comment: Extremely sorry but the alert in my code is after _var rdline = function(parg)_

Comment: Don't be sorry, post your solution as the answer and mark it correct.

Comment: that was not the answer, the alert function didn't copy when I was writing this. I'm pointing out where the alert is in the code.

Comment: You can edit your question and add that to your code.

Comment: So I did edit it to what my current code is...

Comment: If that's your complete code and you have nothing more to add then feel free to browse other questions while you wait for someone who is ready to help you.

Comment: In setLines currset is empty.  Try to put more in the array.

Comment: Where is the tm() function?

Comment: It's not supposed to be there, not sure why I put it there in the first place...
I edited it to make it what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @MatthewSheelerbubster20 How about an up vote for the answer?

Comment: Don't have 15 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `setlines` function you have a loop, which uses `i` as a counter, but you did not use `var` to initialize it, which makes it a global variable:

```
function setLines(cont) {
  // RIGHT HERE, YOU ARE NOT DECLARING i WITH var
  for (i = 0; i < cont.length; i++) {
    if (cont[i] == ";") {
      lines[lc] = currset.join("").replace("<br>", "") + " ";
      lc++;
      currset = [];

    } else {
      currset[i] = cont[i];
    }
  }

  // RIGHT HERE, YOU ARE NOT DECLARING i EITHER, SO THE PREVIOUS
  // i VALUE IS RESET TO ZERO (NOT A PROBLEM YET, BUT IT WILL BE)
  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    rdline(lines[i])
  }
}
```

**And so, `i` becomes a global variable.** Then, in your `rdline` function, you have another loop, that also uses `i`, but again does not declare it:

```
function rdline(parg) {
  //EXECUTING ONCE!
  alert(parg)
  //the rest should be fine
  var pl = [];
  var toplace = [];
  var pcount = 0;

  // USE OF GLOBAL i again! i is again reset to zero
  // This loop allows i to go to a higher value than
  // the first loop that sent you to this one!
  for (i = 0; i < parg.length; i++) {
    if (parg[i] == " ") {
      pl[pcount] = toplace.join("");
      pcount++;
      toplace = [];
    } else {
      toplace[i] = parg[i];
    }
  }
```

It is this loop that uses the same global `i` variable as the first that allows `i` to increment to 36 (the first time `rdline` is called. When `rdline` completes and returns back to the first loop, `i` is bigger than `lines.length` and so the first loop terminates.

The solution is to always declare your looping variables (preferably in the loop) as in:

```
       // Notice the var?
       for(var i = 0; ...
```

And to use **different** looping variables when multiple loops are needed in the same scope. Change the looping variable in function `rdline` to a different name and `var` it in that loop, as in:

```
       // When multiple loops exist in the same scope,
       // always use a different counter for each loop!
       for(var x = 0; ...
```

Remember that in JavaScript, you don't have block level scope by default (you can create block level scope with the new `let` keyword, by the way). Variables set in a function that have not been declared (no `var`) become global and with no block scope (by default), when two (or more) loops use the same looping variable that are in the same scope, one loop will cause the counter to change for all loops within that scope.